# Определить сколько скобок в строке не имеют пары

Tags: python

Дана строка со скобочной последовательностью. Нужно определить сколько неправильно расставлено скобок(неправильные скобки - скобки у которых нет пары).
Я пытался сделать это сам просто банальным способом

```
for i in range(len(st)):
        if st[i] == '(':
            k += 1
        elif st[i] == ')':
            k -= 1
```

Но это все рушится если последовательность выглядит так: ))(( или так ()))(( или так ))((()
Лучше до сих пор не придумал..

Comment: самый банальный способ - последовательно заменять () на ничто

Comment: А что если вот так? `print(st.count("("), st.count(")"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k = 0
wrong = 0
for s in st:
    if s == '(':
        k += 1
    elif s == ')':
        if k == 0: # попытка закрыть скобку, которая не открывалась
            wrong += 1
        else:
            k -= 1
if k > 0: # открытые скобки, которые остались не закрыты
    wrong += k
print(wrong)
```